# Android Tab Selected Image Color

Tags: android, android-tabhost, android-styles, android-style-tabhost

Does Android have a built in mechanism for making an image on a tab look "lit up?" If so, how do I implement it?

Comment: By lit up, do you mean [selected](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4559069/how-do-i-change-the-color-used-to-indicate-a-tab-has-been-selected-on-a-tabhost?rq=1)?

Comment: You'd need to define "lit up"-  you can do pretty much anything with enough effort, but that term alone doesn't really describe the effect you want.

Comment: You're right. What I want is to have an image that is one color when not selected, and a brighter color when it is selected, but the background color to stay the same. I can just make 2 images, but my designer gave me images that make that not so easy.